# Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 guest install on Hyper-V 2012 R2 doesn't have appropriate drivers for LIS?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2, ubuntu-14.04, lis

I have recently created a brand new fresh gen 2 virtual machine on hyper-v and installed the recently released ubuntu 14.04 version.

Even after apt-get update, upon startup, my Windows server 2012 R2 Hyper-V server complains about downlevel drivers in the hyper-v eventlog for

synthetic display driver:
Device 'Microsoft Synthetic Display Controller' in 'Dev Ubuntu 14.04 Gen2' is loaded but has a different version from the server. Server version 3.3 Client version 3.2 (Virtual machine ID 9FC171E7-B2C6-4BD2-9FF0-253209B2A69D). The device will work, but this is an unsupported configuration. This means that technical support will not be provided until this problem is resolved. To fix this problem, upgrade the integration services. To upgrade, connect to the virtual machine and select Insert Integration Services Setup Disk from the Action menu. (of course this doesn't seem to work)

and

data exchange integration service:
Hyper-V Data Exchange connected to virtual machine 'Dev Ubuntu 14.04 Gen2', but the version does not match the version expected by Hyper-V (Virtual machine ID 9FC171E7-B2C6-4BD2-9FF0-253209B2A69D). Framework version: Negotiated (3.0) - Expected (3.0); Message version: Negotiated (4.0) - Expected (5.0). This is an unsupported configuration. This means that technical support will not be provided until this problem is resolved. To fix this problem, upgrade the integration services. To upgrade, connect to the virtual machine and select Insert Integration Services Setup Disk from the Action menu (similarly, this doesn't seem to work).

Also, hyper-v complains that about the "Integration Services: Update required" in the Summary tab withing the Windows 2012 R2 hyper-V Manager.

My (evidently mistaken) belief was that the Linux Integration Services had been integrated into the kernel, and thus Trusty would be compatible with 2012 R2 hyper-v services.

Can anyone explain where /how to obtain the updated Integration Services packages for 14.04 and the correct installation procedure so that my ubuntu virtual machines become fully supported using hyper-v 2012 r2?

Many thanks for your help,
Doug Coleman

Comment: This type of question is not really suited for StackOverflow.SE, but rather for [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com/), since it is not directly related to programming topics.

Answer (score 4):

Data Exchange can be activated manually:

```
# sudo apt-get update
# sudo apt-get install hv-kvp-daemon-init
```

Reboot the virtual machine afterwards for the daemons to start.

See the whole article on Ubuntu VM on Hyper-V for further reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531029.aspx

Comment: Thx .installation was possible that way, i have some  hv_vmbus... processes now, but actually copy/paste from Win8.1 host to Ubuntu 14 LTS guest does not work. shouldn't it ?

Comment: As far as I know it shouldn't, meaning the Data Exchange doesn't include the copy/paste "exchange".

Answer (score 3):

[That's expected behavior](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2956569). Hyper-V is basically saying "you're not using a windows operating system". Even though the drivers are fully supported, the Hyper-V client API is NOT fully implemented in the Hyper-V Linux drivers like they are in the Windows drivers (most notably the key/value system). Those not implemented features of the client API in the Linux driver is enough to set off the warning in Hyper-V Manager.